# Solution for regex of english contractions doesn't work

Tags: python, regex, nltk

I am currently fiddling around with Regular Expressions and NLTK (Natural Language Toolkit). I want to tokenize sentences into words and punctuation. Contractions like "can't", "I'll" and so on should be recognised as words as well. I can't seem to find a regular expression that does this.

```
\w+(\'\w+)?|[!-~]
```

Why doesn't this regex work? I only get bad results like:

```
['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

For sentences like these:

```
This is a test. Lulz another sentence. This can't be real.
```

I am afraid that I haven't understood Regular Expressions?

EDIT:

Code:

```
import re

re.findall("\w+('\w+)?|[!-~]", "This is a test. Lulz another sentence. This can't be real.")
```

Comment: Show the code you actually used the regex to get that bad result.

Comment: Use a non-capturing group - `r"\w+(?:'\w+)?|[!-~]"`

Comment: You've written `\'w` instead of `'\w`. Why is this closed as a dupe when it's clearly this typo that breaks the regex? @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Who has marked this as a duplicate? I don't think the issue lies with the regex funciton but with the expression.

Comment: @Norrius That is OP typo. The only fix that is really necessary is a non-capturing group.

Comment: `\w+(\'\w+)?|[!-~]` still doesnt work. The non-capturing group doesn't return the contraction as a word.

Comment: @New2HTML Yes, the issue is the capturing group. A non-capturing group syntax is **`(?:...)`**.

Comment: Yeah now it works, must have done something wrong. But I thought the `?` after the `(\'\w+)` makes it non-capturing?

Comment: @New2HTML No, that makes it optional.

Comment: Could you remove the duplicate? And what is the difference between optional and non-capturing? I can't wrap my head around this.